# How do I plot an axis object?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an axes object that I previously did not plot.

```
_,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(range(10))
plt.close()
```

I now want to plot it. How do I do it? I know it can be done because I pass the ax object to wandb.ai API to plot on their dashboards.

Comment: plt.show() at the end instead of plt.close.

Comment: Yeah but that's why I said that I didn't previously plot it. I want to plot it somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @BorunChowdhury. Once you close it, it's too late. You can call `plt.show()` anywhere in the code as long as the figure is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`plt.close`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html) closes the last figure you worked on. Once a figure is closed, you will not be able to plot it.

[`plt.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) will display all open figures no matter where you call it. So as long as you remove the call to `close`, you can call `show` later in your code.

The red herring here is that you are able to plot by passing an [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html) object to wandb.ai. Closing a figure does not necessarily destroy the underlying data and display metadata: it just destroys its ability to show up in the current GUI. Closing the figure does not prevent a valid `Axes` object from being passed to the online API wrapper, and serialized data from being sent to the server. It just prevents the enclosing [`Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html) object from being displayed locally.